# Converting projectile simulation to 3D causes drawing to disasppear?

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, freeglut, opengl-compat

I have a code that successfully draws projectiles in 2D, but I need to apply changes to make it in 3D.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define g 9.8
#define PI 3.14
#define ESC 27



void initialize(void)
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 1000, 0, 500);
}

static void keyPressFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key) {
        case ESC:
            exit(1);
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    float Pheta, Pheta2, Pheta3,Pheta4, Vo, time, time_top, d1, d2, d3, Uox1, Uox2, Uox3;
    Vo = 60;
    Pheta = 60;
    Pheta2 = 30;
    Pheta3 = 40;
    Pheta4 = 50;
    time = (2 * Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180)) / g;
    time_top = time/2;
    d1 = 500;
    d2 = 650;
    d3 = 800;

    Uox1 = (d1 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 2)/2;
    Uox2 = (d2 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180)*  time_top)/time_top;
    Uox3 = (d3 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 8)/8;


    for(float t=0; t < 12 ; t += 0.0005)
    {
        float x1 = (Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * t);
        float y1 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x2 = (d1 - Uox1 * t);
        float y2 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x3 = (d2 - Uox2 * t);
        float y3 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x4 = (d3 - Uox3 * t);
        float y4 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(x1, y1);
        glVertex2d(x2, y2);
        glVertex2d(x3, y3);
        glVertex2d(x4, y4);

        if  (x1+0.1 >= x4 && x4+0.1 >= x1)
        {
            break;
        }

        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("C-Lang-Project");

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressFunc);

    initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

To make it 3D, I changed glVertex2d into glVertex3d, set a variable z and added it to the glVertex3d.
The final code that I've got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define g 9.8
#define PI 3.14
#define ESC 27


void initialize(void)
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D(0, 1000, 0, 500);
}

static void keyPressFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key) {
        case ESC:
            exit(1);
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    float Pheta, Pheta2, Pheta3,Pheta4, Vo, time, time_top, d1, d2, d3, Uox1, Uox2, Uox3, z;
    Vo = 60;
    Pheta = 60;
    Pheta2 = 30;
    Pheta3 = 40;
    Pheta4 = 50;
    time = (2 * Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180)) / g;
    time_top = time/2;
    d1 = 500;
    d2 = 650;
    d3 = 800;
    z = 15;

    Uox1 = (d1 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 2)/2;
    Uox2 = (d2 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180)*  time_top)/time_top;
    Uox3 = (d3 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 8)/8;

    for(float t=0; t < 12 ; t += 0.0005)
    {
        float x1 = (Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * t);
        float y1 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x2 = (d1 - Uox1 * t);
        float y2 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x3 = (d2 - Uox2 * t);
        float y3 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        float x4 = (d3 - Uox3 * t);
        float y4 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3d(x1, y1, z);
        glVertex3d(x2, y2, z);
        glVertex3d(x3, y3, z);
        glVertex3d(x4, y4, z);

        if  (x1+0.1 >= x4 && x4+0.1 >= x1)
        {
            break;
        }

        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("C-Lang-Project");

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressFunc);

    initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

But it does not show any mistake, just shows a black window.

P.S. I am using OpenGL & freeglut

Comment: The Z-range on that `glOrtho2D()` projection matrix is +/-1 so if your Z coordinates are outside that your geometry will get clipped away.  Perhaps you were thinking of `gluPerspective()` & an appropriate `gluLookAt()` call?

Comment: @genpfault, If I use last two functions, do I need a glOrtho2D or glOrtho function?

Comment: Nope, no ortho anything in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene is clipped by by the near plane of the orthographic projection.

The `z` coordiante of the geoemtry is set `z=15;` but the orthographic projection is set `gluOrtho2D(0, 1000, 0, 500);`. [`gluOrtho2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) sets a near plane of -1 and a far plane of 1.
The view space `z` coordinate has to be between the near and far plane.
Since the view space z axis points out of the viewport, the view space z coordinate is -15.

This means, if `z=15` then the following condition has to be fulfilled:

```
near < -15 < far
```

Change the orthographic projection to solve the issue. Use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

e.g.

```cpp
void initialize(void)
{
    // [...]

    glOrtho(0, 1000, 0, 500, -20, 1);
}
```

---

Of course it is possible to switch to perspective projection. In this case you've to invert the and z coordinate.
To get all the geometry on the screen (in clip space), I recommend to increase the amount to of the z coordinate and (of course) the distance to the far plane:

e.g.

```cpp
void display(void)
{
    float z = -500;

    // [...]
}
```

```cpp
void initialize(void)
{
    // [...]


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 90.0, 1000.0 / 500.0, 0.1, 1000.0 );
}
```

---

Don't implement a render loop in the event processing loop. Use [`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html) to force the display to be repainted:

```cpp
float t=0;

void display(void)
{
    float Pheta, Pheta2, Pheta3,Pheta4, Vo, time, time_top, d1, d2, d3, Uox1, Uox2, Uox3, z;
    Vo = 60;  Pheta = 60; Pheta2 = 30; Pheta3 = 40; Pheta4 = 50;
    time = (2 * Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180)) / g;
    time_top = time/2; d1 = 500; d2 = 650; d3 = 800;
    z = 15;

    Uox1 = (d1 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 2)/2;
    Uox2 = (d2 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180)*  time_top)/time_top;
    Uox3 = (d3 - Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * 8)/8;

    float x1 = (Vo * cos(Pheta * PI / 180) * t);
    float y1 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);
    float x2 = (d1 - Uox1 * t);
    float y2 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);
    float x3 = (d2 - Uox2 * t);
    float y3 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);
    float x4 = (d3 - Uox3 * t);
    float y4 = (Vo * sin(Pheta * PI / 180) * t - 0.5 * g * t * t);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3d(x1, y1, z);
    glVertex3d(x2, y2, z);
    glVertex3d(x3, y3, z);
    glVertex3d(x4, y4, z);
    glEnd();

    t += 0.0005;

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it still does not work properly. Also, if I add glOrtho it shows an error "undefined reference to 'glOrtho' ". If I do not use glOrtho, then it just shows a black screen, but few seconds after there is just one green point.

Comment: @PakSergey Are you sure that you've no type? It is [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)? Since the other OpenGL instructions a valid, it should be valid, too.

Comment: @Rabbit76, I don't know where is the problem here, but it just does show an error. Here is the screenshot of the window: https://www.flickr.com/photos/157855156@N08/47756963812/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: This is what I get if I don't use glOrtho function.

Comment: @PakSergey Of course, but you've to use either `glOrtho` or `gluPerspective`.

Comment: @PakSergey Try something like `glTranslate(-1,-1,0); glScale(2.0/1000.0,2.0/500.0, 1.0);` instead of `glOrtho`

Comment: now it shows the same undefined reference error for these glTranslate and glScale functions.... Maybe there is problem with OpenGL version?

Comment: @PakSergey `#include <GL/gl.h>`